# Xcode - HM10 Bluetooth BLE app

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I had a question regarding a specific task I which to fulfill involving my iPhone application and the Bluetooth HM-10 module.

With our app we have an established connection with the module and we have a text box that can send the value typed by a user to the module to then turn on some LED lights depending on what value is sent.

We want to change this so instead of a user typing in a value on a text box they can use a slider to send a value between 0 and 6 instead. Whatever the slider is currently on it will send that value to the HM10 BLE module.

We have tried for hours but are unable to alter our code to enable the slider to send the value instead of a given text box.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!